# Building SSIS .dtproj inside a VSTS Hosted Build Agent

Tags: ssis, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build a SSIS 2016 project, that's been configured with the Project Deployment model in a VSTS build with the intent to deploy the .ispac file onto a SQL Server VM hosted in Azure.

Using MSBuild to build the project file returns the following error:

```
The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. 
If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the  element. 
If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.
```

I found a blog post here describing the same issue

https://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/

However, the solution depends on installed SQL Server Data Tools into a build agent.

Is there a method where I can use a VSTS Hosted agent, and not have to create an on-premises agent with SSDT installed?

Comment: Please vote here if you think it's about time for MSBuild to support SSxS projects: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/523612/support-ssis-ssrs-ssas-in-msbuild.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just released new Extension for VSTS/TFS

https://github.com/ToxicGlobe/VSTS-SSIS-Extension

It build Visual Studio project, containing packages and parameters to a project deployment file (.ispac)

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TG.VSTS-SSIS

Comment: This answer could be improved by describing what the extension does.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: It's worth noting that SSDT should also be installed on the build server with _SQL Server Integration Services_ selected, and it should be installed using the standalone installer from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt). Of particular note is where it states: _"For most users, SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) is installed during Visual Studio installation. Installing SSDT using the Visual Studio installer adds the base SSDT functionality, so **you still need to run the SSDT standalone installer to get AS, IS, and RS tools**."_

Answer (score 1):

For similar scenario i used devenv.exe

Tool : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Arguments : .\Code\Database\NameOfSolution.sln /build $(BuildConfiguration)

devenv.exe /build does not require ssdt to installed on build agent

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but it didn't work for me. 
I did the following

Tool: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" 
Args: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\folder\solution.sln /Build $(BuildConfiguration) /Project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\folder\project\project.dtproj /ProjectConfig Development

Then in the UpgradeLog.htm

folder\project.dtproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=647009&projecttype=159641D6-6404-4A2A-AE62-294DE0FE8301

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Microsoft is not supporting this just yet based off UserVoice

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/11543292-install-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-for-sql-serve

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/4850300-install-sql-server-data-tools-for-bi-on-the-team-f